# Imagemagick error in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an error while running my project. I'm not able to find what is the problem. Can anyone help me?

The error is:

```
/home/kranthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails301/gems/rmagick-2.9.1/lib/RMagick2.so:
libMagickCore.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory -
/home/kranthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails301/gems/rmagick-2.9.1/lib/RMagick2.so (LoadError)
```

Comment: `libMagickCore.so.2` seems odd; Ubuntu 11.04 packaged `libmagickcore3`. If you want to use an older `libMagickCore.so` you might need to go to some effort to get the older package installed. Or maybe try to find a gem that works with the newer version. Or recompile the gem to use the new library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rmagick [2.9.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick/versions/2.9.1) was released in 2009 which is why it's looking for an old version of ImageMagick as sarnold said. I'd recommend upgrading to a [newer version](https://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick) of rmagick such as [2.13.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick/versions/2.13.1) and make sure you have the [imagemagick Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/graphics/imagemagick) installed.

Comment: Is that a problem with imagemagick or rmagick? do i need to install latest version of Imagemagick? if so where can i find latest imagemagick package?

Comment: Just run `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` that will ensure you have a recent Ubuntu package.

The error you pasted shows that the rmagick version you're using is about 3 years old. So it's the problem. To upgrade it, find the corresponding line in either your `Gemfile` or your `config/environment.rb` file (for Rails 3 and 2.3 respectively) and set the version to `2.13.1`. If you don't find a line for rmagick, just add one. Then run `bundle install` or `rake gems:install`.